# Unable to see USB 3.0 harddrive unless connected through USB 2.0

Tags: usb, mount

I recently found that I am unable to see my external usb harddrive on my Ubuntu guest VM. However, I am able to view contents on my host windows 10.

Even more peculiar is that this only happens on usb 3.0. With usb 2.0, I am able to view the external harddrive on Ubuntu guest VM.

I can confirm with a different external harddrive on usb 3.0 that I can see the disk and mount it.

I have tried running chkdsk while mounted on Windows, there were no errors reported or any issues to fix.

I have tried using different cables, Ubuntu VM still can't see the harddrive.

While using usb 3.0:

from /var/log/kern.log:

```
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.057835] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.082809] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab26, bcdDevice= 1.07
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.082813] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.082815] usb 4-1: Product: BUP Slim BK
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.082816] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.082817] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: NA7Y6BTV
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.089866] scsi host33: uas
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.092329] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.092414] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 data cmplt err -32 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Sep 17 21:11:58 presto kernel: [54287.092418] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
Sep 17 21:12:18 presto kernel: [54307.810812] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Sep 17 21:12:18 presto kernel: [54307.810820] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 CDB: Inquiry 12 00 00 00 24 00
Sep 17 21:12:18 presto kernel: [54307.826485] scsi host33: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.959706] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.990112] scsi host33: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.992180] usb 4-1: stat urb: status -32
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.995345] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.995349] scsi 33:0:0:0: tag#16 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54307.995352] scsi host33: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54308.232431] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54308.267987] scsi host33: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
Sep 17 21:12:19 presto kernel: [54308.267991] scsi 33:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 017: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

No luck with lsblk or `fdisk -l`:

```
$ lsblk | grep -v loop
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    50G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    50G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

While using usb 2.0
from /var/log/kern.log:

```
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54442.691706] usb 3-4.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.068445] usb 3-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab26, bcdDevice= 1.07
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.068448] usb 3-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.068450] usb 3-4.1: Product: BUP Slim BK
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.068452] usb 3-4.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.068453] usb 3-4.1: SerialNumber: NA7Y6BTV
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.073959] scsi host33: uas
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.076452] scsi 33:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BK      0107 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.080735] sd 33:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.189103] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.189105] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.189899] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.189901] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.191431] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.192963] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.209267]  sdb: sdb1
Sep 17 21:14:34 presto kernel: [54443.221130] sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

lsblk:

```
$ lsblk | grep -v loop
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    50G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    50G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /media/kennzors/kennzors01
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x08129a8d

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any recommendations and pointers to get this working on usb 3.0 would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a potential solution from [vmware forums](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/570091)

```
To check if your drive is not working with UAS enabled:

Connect drive to guest
Run dmesg in a terminal; some errors will be logged (in my case, they were highlighted red)
Disabling UAS for your drive:

Run lsusb - note the ID of your drive (example: 0bc2:02322)
Run sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_uas.conf
Add the following line to the file:
options usb-storage quirks=ADD ID HERE:u (example using above ID: options usb-storage quirks=0bc2:02322:u)
Exit nano (Control + X, then Y to save)
Run sudo update-initramfs -u; sudo reboot
```

I guess my followup question is, does this mean that I won't get USB 3.0 speeds?

Comment: Thanks. this works for me. Not sure it's fast enough or not but on my mSATA device, the device performs at 112MB/sec read, 75MB/sec write.